# Passing data from a UITableView to another ViewController depending on what row is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I have two ViewControllers one which contains a UITextView and the other one contains a UITableView. I would like my app to pass data for the selected row from the SecondViewController which contains the UITableView to the UITextView in the first ViewController depending on what row the user select. I am using the below code in the firstViewController (Just to give you a bit of history what I have is a UITextView inside the firstViewController and the user have the option of either entering a custom value or exert a longpressgesture then a popover Window get displayed containing the UITableView in the secondViewController. What I would like to achieve is when a row is selected from the popoverView which contains the UItableView the popoverView get closed and the value highlighted in the table get displayed in the UITextView in the firstViewController):

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView: UITextView! 

        var textInsideIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView: String? = nil

     override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.text = textInsideIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView

indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.attributedText = placeholderTextInIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView

        }

    }
```

and the below code in the secondViewController:

```
@objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UITableViewCell?) {

            let toFirstViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

            if let indexPath = self.indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let selectedRow = years[indexPath.row]

                toFirstViewController.textInsideIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView = selectedRow

            }

            }

}
```

However, when I run the simulator and select a row from the table nothing happens inside the UITextView in the firstViewController? All what happens is that the firstViewController gets displayed. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Shadi.

Comment: Why is the `prepare(for:sender:)` method inside the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method?

Comment: I am new to coding so I might have the wrong understanding, I want the information to be passed once a row is highlighted in the table?

Comment: Fine. But again, why is one method inside another? Don't do that. Move `prepare(for:sender:)` outside of the other method.

Comment: I did what you mentioned ready but I am still having the same issue. The data is not being transferred all what is happening is that the firstViewController gets displayed with no updates to the UITextView inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as:

```
@objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "<set identifier String>", sender: indexPath)

}


func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {

            let toFirstViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

            if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
                print("indexPath - \(indexPath)")
                let selectedRow = years[indexPath.row]
                 print("selectedRow - \(selectedRow)")
                toFirstViewController.textInsideIndicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView = selectedRow

            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Krunal, I did what you mentioned above but still same problem as before. I amended my code as I am inserting a placeholder text inside the UITextView in the firstViewController manually. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I am also using a CustomCell inside the UITableView if that helps.

Comment: Print `selectedRow` in your segue method and check, do you get selected row or not. Also print 'indexPath'.

Comment: No it does not print the value and I receive this error "Warning: Attempt to present <Popover_ViewController_with_UITableView.ViewController: 0x7fbcc851df30> on <Popover_ViewController_with_UITableView.IndicativeDesignWorkingLifeVC: 0x7fbcc860f780> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: Just to give you a bit of history what I have is a UITextView inside the firstViewController and the user have the option of either entering a custom value or exert a longpressgesture then a popover Window get displayed containing the UITableView in the secondViewController. What I would like to achieve is when a row is selected from the popoverView which contains the UItableView the popoverView get closed and the value highlighted in the table get displayed in the UITextView in the firstViewController.